# Nagios/Icinga check of Windows disk space, wrong -l argument

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, debian-squeeze, nagios, icinga

I'm using NSClient++ on the Windows servers and all other checks are working fine. I'm using the default nt_check config, but these show up as "services unknown"

define service{
    use         generic-service
    host_name       winserver
    service_description C:\ Drive Space
    check_command       check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l c -w 80 -c 90
    }

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or can suggest a better nt_check?

Comment: my final solution to this problem was to use NRPE (check_nrpe) to check the free disk space and not use check_nt

Of course this isn't working for all of my Windows servers (on one network all the disk checks timeout), but I suspect that is router/firewall issue

Answer (score 0):

I was with same problem. My solution was put password in NSC.ini(remove ; on password-secret-password) and put same password in file commands.cfg (check_nt) use parameter -s YourPassword in end of the line command_line.